# Error: Cannot find module '@expo/image-utils'

Tags: react-native, expo

I had recently updated to latest expo-cli version available but after installing it when I tried to start my app it throws an error "Error Cannot find module '@expo/image-utils'"

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR3k4.png)

I tried finding the error solution on Github, I saw the chat of the collaborators of the @expo/expo-cli in which they have said that they have resolved this solution but it's not resolved yet.

Comment: What is your `expo-cli` version?